# Webview page appears noticeably lighter the first time app is launched in Android 13

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

We have a hybrid Android app and it is showing an odd behaviour that I can't really figure out.

When the app is launched for the first time after installation, the screen appears noticeably lighter in colour. If you close (swipe away) and launch it again, the colour appears normal. The screenshot shows, the top image is from the first launch, the bottom one from subsequent launches.

[image]

It only seems to happen on Android 13 devices. Any ideas on what might be causing it would be appreciated.

Comment: Any extra frameworks involved? Just android SDK & webview? Which SDK version? It sounds like a theming issue with a launch activity. Maybe SplashScreen is grabbing a particular theme?

Comment: As a clue: It's not just the font weight changing. The icon spacing at the top is changing, and I suspect a lot of other elements are too. It's likely due to how / when the theme is being applied.

Comment: Do you know about the layout inspector (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector)? It allows you to analyze the current view of the phone. Maybe there is just a semi-transparent element over the webpage. A cookie banner or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, I've moved on to some other projects now, but when I get a chance I'll try a few things